# pylint: disable a message for a given module, using .pylintrc file

Tags: python, pylint

From the [pylint docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-message-for-a-particular-module-only) I see it's possible to disable a message for a particular module (or even block) by adding the appropriate pylint comment in the right place.

Is it possible to get the same functionality by adding to the `.pylintrc` file instead? For example, can I disable a certain check for my tests directory without adding pylint comments to each file and instead using the `.pylintrc` file?

Comment: you can use the 'ignore' option to skip specific directories, e.g. `ignore=test`

Comment: Yup, from the docs it looks like you can skip all linting on specific directories. But I can't find information about skipping specific checks for specific directories (or files).

Comment: I don't think you can do that beside with inline comment